# How to block safari browser using .htacess and allow other browsers to acess my site

Tags: .htaccess

Hi im newbie  and I am creating a chat website in that I want to block safari browser (should work for other users who are not using safari) , i searched in google and found it can be done using **.htacess** , so please any one help me , how to do it

i tried this following things

```
        Options -Indexes
```

and also this

```
       order allow deny
       deny from all
       allow from 192.126.12.199
```

I know this all are for some other diffrent purpose  , so any one please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , it may be helpful

```
     SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" permitted=1
```

To block Firefox

```
         BrowserMatchNoCase Firefox\D+[0-3]\.[\d.]* legacy=firefox
```

To block chrome

```
         BrowserMatchNoCase Chrome\D+[0-9]\.[\d.]* legacy=chrome
```

To block safari

```
         BrowserMatchNoCase Safari\D+(?:[0-4]+|\d?53[0-3]\.[\d.]*) legacy=safari
```

Then complete it with

```
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from env=banned
       Allow from env=permitted
```